# The connection to _next/webpack-hmr was interrupted while the page was loading

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mobx

Using Next.js - building [this](https://github.com/archae0pteryx/depth-charge-nextjs)

I am porting my app to the `next.js` framework. Currently, I am re-creating the authentication system, otherwise, this iteration of my app is pretty bare-bones. All of a sudden, after adding my protected routes (Higher Order Components) - not sure if that is related - I started getting this error along with super clunky loading (obviously).

The connection to `http://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr` was interrupted while the page was loading.

Otherwise, everything works as expected.

I have no idea how to even begin to troubleshoot this sort of thing. Does anyone have any ideas of how I might get a bit more info/insight on this problem? Guidance on how to debug? My next move is to start disconnecting things until it goes away I guess. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: This happens in Firefox not Chrome

Comment: Yes I to get this error in firefox not chrome, I wonder what is causing it.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1109) you can find some workarounds, but not an official solution.

Comment: has this been solved?

Comment: This happened to me with dynamic imports, I removed the dynamic import and the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

As per the resolution suggested in https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9776, You can unregister the service worker if you are using CRA.

The following code shows the way to remove registered service worker:

`import { unregister } from './serviceWorker'`

`// ...
unregister();`

If you have already deployed the registered one, first you to need build this code and deploy again it will deploy with unregistered one. The reason for doing this is because the service worker is registered in your users' browsers if you've used register before. unregister removes it entirely, though. If you build you app again, the main JS bundle will get a new hash, the users will download it, and unregister will remove it for them.

Answer (score 1):

Have had the same issue.

I followed recommendations from various sources I researched and none of them worked. In my case it was an issue in next.config.js file.

More specifically, in my next.config.js file I was including an async generateBuildId function but I left it blank in order to revisit the algorithm at a later stage since the project was in its early stage. After returning a valid buildID from this function the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: this happened to me using Firefox, connecting to `localhost`;
same error:

```
The connection to http://localhost:9009/__webpack_hmr 
  was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

> Being specific I was running `start-storybook -p 9009 -s public`, but that's actually unrelated to the issue.

---

I solved this clearing Cached Web Content and Site Data at Firefox preferences:

[image: 'clear data' menu from Firefox preferences, both combo-boxes 'cookies and site data' and 'cached web content' are selected]

Comment: To my surprise this actually worked for me. I only cleared cookies and cache from the last hour, restarted my dev server and things were working again. Certainly more convenient than restarting my computer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a challenge with Websockets or SocketIO. You might have an incorrect configuration or setup running in your app. Remove the imports or get the right config in place.

Answer (score -1):

This usually happens when you are developing the app

The issue might be service work that is getting register to the browser again and again in development mode as the browsers reload fully,

open the Dev tool and check whether a service worker is a registered or not.

if it registers then unregister it, and update your next.config.js so that the service worker will not register again in the browser

I am using "next-pwa" module, below is the check which i have done

```
  pwa: {
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    register: true,
    scope: '/',
    dest: 'public',
    swSrc: 'service-worker.js',
  },
```